# Finding equations for a subspace in non-standard operations

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a Vector space $\Bbb V$ with these non-standard operations (with component to component multiplication)

[A]$_i$$_j$ $\oplus$ [B]$_i$$_j$ =[A]$_i$$_j$ . [B]$_i$$_j$  **and**

$\alpha$[A]$_i$$_j$=[A$^\alpha$]$_i$$_j$

Say S is a subspace in $\Bbb V$  generated by A=$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 8 \\ \end{pmatrix} $ and B=$ \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 8 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} $

How do you find the equations for this subspace?

Comment: if the left hand side of the first question is defined by its right hand side.... what does the rhs mean?  i.e. what does $[A]_{ij}\cdot [B]_{ij}$ mean?  Is it component-wise multiplication?

Comment: Yes, its component to component multiplication